# Share memory between multiple process in nodejs environment

Tags: node.js

So here is the problem, on which i'm thinking of:

One physical server running node js http server through cluster module, which means that there are multiple separate process, each second I'm receiving large amount of requests (5000-10000k), each process counting it's incoming request separately, and then they aggregate this statistics in memcache.

Such architecture creates additional processor time consumption on i/o operation + additional large service running on same server.

What I'm thinking about is to create small service, which allocates some memory for request counters, after that, when http server processes starts - they connect to this service and receive from it pointer on memory, where counter located, so they can increment and read number directly from it without intermediate service commands.

**Question:** Is there any way to allocate memory in one process and then give pointer address of this memory to a multiple set of another process so this set of processes could read and write that memory directly? And this should be possible in node js.

**Answer:** After some researches i had come across shared memory system calls and used them in self written nodejs ad-don, that allowed me to use single memory block among multiple processes. Disadvantage of this method is that only primitive types allowed (char, int)

Comment: I don't fully understand the question .. do you want to implement caching on a cluster?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Main question: is there any way to allocate memory in one process and then give pointer address of this memory to a multiple set of another process so this set of processes could read and write that memory directly. And this should be possible in node js